# Regular Expression: Extract pairs of values from strings that do not start with "#"

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file that contains the following:

```
# This is a comment, do not parse this: U20:%x[-2,1]
U01:%x[-2,1]
U02:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]
```

The requirement is that I need to extract out the value pairs within each square parenthesis in each line.

For eg. for the first line I expect to get the pair -2 and 1. 
For the second line, I expect 3 pairs of values.

The line should start with a "U" followed by at least 1 digit, followed by a colon ":".

If the line is empty or starts with "#", then it should be ignored.

This was the regex I used, but it's not ignoring lines starting with the "#".

```
(?:U\d+:|/)\%x\[(?:(-?\d+),(\d+))\]
```

How I can I change the regex to make it work?

Comment: What implementation of regex are you using? Programming language? Text editor etc...

Comment: Is it really necessary to make a giant complex regex to check to see if the string starts with a `#`? Can't you just use `str.charAt(0) != '#'` to strip the lines you want to ignore? (This would probably be faster and more understandable too)

Answer (score 12):

You can use this pattern with a global research:

```
(?m:^U\d+:|\G/)%x\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\]
```

pattern details:

```
(?m:                # non capturing group with the multiline modifier
    ^               # anchor: start of the line
    U\d+:           # literal "U" followed by digits and : 
  |                 # OR
    \G/             # literal "/" contiguous to a precedent match 
)
%x\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\]
```

example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m:^U\\d+:|\\G/)%x\\[(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s); // s is all the content of your txt file
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2));
}
```

If something else between two `%x[a,b]` is allowed, you can change the pattern to:

```
(?m:^U\d+:|\G(?>[^#\n/]++|/(?!%x\[))*/)%x\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\]
```

or

```
(?m:^U\d+:|\G[^#\n]*?/)%x\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\]
```

*note that the added subpattern can't match a comment since the character `#` is exclude from the character class*

Another way: since your data are in a text file, you can read the file line by line and extract the numbers with one of the precedent patterns (in this case you can remove the m modifier). The advantage is that you know what line are the numbers from.

Comment: Great answer **+1**. One small detail, the second digit might be negative (I suppose), so maybe you should add `-?` to it. And who knows, `[+-]?` might also be commendable...

Comment: @HamZa: Thanks, I don't know if the sign is needed with the second integer, but I will add it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use REGEX `(?:[^\\[]*)(?:\\[)(-?\\d+),(\\d+)(?=\\])` to find matches between `[` and `]` .

**Explanation :**

[image]

[image]

**CODE:**

```
String ar[] ={ "# This is a comment, do not parse this: U20:%x[-2,1]",
               "U01:%x[-2,1]",
               "U02:%x[-2,1]/%x[-1,1]/%x[0,1]"};

String REGEX = "(?:[^\\[]*)(?:\\[)(-?\\d+),(\\d+)(?=\\])";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
for(String theString:ar){
    if(!theString.matches("^U\\d+:.*"))
            continue;

    Matcher m = p.matcher(theString);
    while (m.find()) {
        String matched = m.group(1);
        String matched1 = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("Mached :  "+ matched +", "+ matched1);

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Mached :  -2, 1
Mached :  -2, 1
Mached :  -1, 1
Mached :  0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a text editor with regex functionality (there are loads, I like notepad++) then you might be able to do this by first removing the comments. I think it's the simplest way. Perform the following replacement regex:

```
^(?: |\t)*#.*?$
```

And use an empty string as the replacement. Then you are in no danger of matching comments with your original expression (assuming the comment character hash always appears at the start of the line).

```
(?:U\d+:|/)\%x\[(?:(-?\d+),(\d+))\]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am writing an app that needs to parse the lines in a text file and I was trying to avoid doing any additional pre-processing.
That said, if the are no pure regex ways to do it, I would have to resort to pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in to java, but this one seem to do it:

```
(?:^#.*?$|^U\d+|%x\[(-?\d+),(-?\d+)\])
```

using global, multi line mode.

Expl.: (Non capturing) match either -

1. a full line begining with a #
2. the start of a valid line (Un)
3. or the actual data

If option three is the match, grab the actual values.
Since the alternatives are executed in order all comment lines will be "removed".

Maybe you'll need some adoption for it to work in java.

[Check it out here](http://regex101.com/r/fN5tF0)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this work :

```
([^#]?:U\d+:|/)\%x\[(?:(-?\d+),(\d+))\]
```

we add [^#] at the begining after the ( that means not start with #

Answer (score 0):

My friend this will works for you

```
public static void main(String []args){

    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    String line="";

    try {
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<file_path>"));

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m:^U\\d+:|\\G/)%x\\[(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\]");

        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

        Matcher m = p.matcher(line); 
        while (m.find()) {

            System.out.println(m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2));
        }

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    finally{

        try {
            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
    }







}
```

Comment: @swirlobt My friend is that you want

Answer (score 0):

dude here is a simple RegEx:

```
\[-*\d+,-*\d+\]
```

that's it!!!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler trick will do the work in the multiline mode:

```
(?m)(?:(?:#.*$)|%x\[(-?\d+),(\d+)\])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest decompose the problem in several step 
1st : iterate through all line, skipping the comments (line started by a #)
2nd : for each line that is not a comment, extract the strings in between brackets

// Holds the answer
ArrayList valuePairs = new ArrayList();

// Read the file line by line
bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(""));

while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    // skip the comments
    if(line.charAt(0) == '#') continue;

```
// finds value pairs (start and ends with a bracket, brackets not included)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line); 
while (m.find()) 
{

    valuePairs.add(m.group(0));
}
```

}

This code has been written outside of an IDE, I assume some try/catch are missing but the idea is there.

Answer (score -2):

If your regex almost works for you, you just need to prefix it with a line start "^":

```
^(?:U\d+:|/)\%x\[(?:(-?\d+),(\d+))\]
```

Comment: Regex works, but when you try to limit the matching cases by using `^` they will limit to the first match then.

Comment: Yes indeed, it only match the first pair: http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/#!;t=U06%3A%25x%5B-22%2C0%5D%2F%25x%5B13%2C0%5D%0A%23%20comment%0Aa%20U06%3A%25x%5B-22%2C0%5D%2F%25x%5B13%2C0%5D&r=%5E(%3F%3AU%5Cd%2B%3A%7C%2F)%5C%25x%5C%5B(%3F%3A(-%3F%5Cd%2B)%2C(%5Cd%2B))%5C%5D&x=